# Why isn't the tonic syllable in "varies" not the same as in "variety"?

Tags: differences, pronunciation

I've always pronounced "varies" as /veəˈrɪz/ but recently heard someone say /ˈveərɪz/ in a video. I'm brazilian, so that causes me some confusion as I'm not used to speaking English on a daily basis.

What is it that makes "variety" have its tonic syllable placed differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbs don’t change their stress pattern just because they get a 3rd-person singular inflection.  Thus since *vary* is /ˈveri/, *varies* must be /ˈveriz/.

It always works this way.

In the more complexly tetrasyllabic *variety*, the first and third vowels are reduced, so /vəˈraɪ.ɪ̈ti/.  The same vowels in stressed and unstressed positions are no more apt to be alike in English than they are in Portuguese.

Comment: I think I've never used the word "vary" before, but if I did before reading this I'd certainly pronounce it /veˈri/. Thanks :)